# SharePoint 2016 Calendar - Can you send a SharePoint Calendar event via Outlook? Even without any mapping of the SharePoint calendar?

Tags: javascript, 2016, custom-list, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

So what I would like to do, from within a 2016 SharePoint Calendar, is to double-click a calendar event and click some kind of button that then opens up a meeting event in my Outlook, with all of the SharePoint Calendar event details (time and date and title, etc.) so that I can email that instance to another user's Outlook email.  Basically, I would love to create some kind of functionality that opens an Outlook invite with the SharePoint calendar event info prefilled into the Outlook meeting invite so that I can easily send misc. SharePoint calendar events to peoples' Outlook calendar.

I know that I can always have everyone map the SharePoint calendar to their outlook, but not everyone will need to have every single SharePoint calendar event in their personal Outlook calendar. This type of end result would allow people to easily forward events of interest to specific people without the ask of having everyone map the SHarePoint calendar and for them to only pay attention to specific events.

Does anyone know if this functionality might be possible or have any alternative methods to achieve what I am after?  Thanks!

Comment: The whole calendar or just a singular event?

Comment: Just a singular event. Basically, everyone has their specific tasks that they work, but when they need someone else to cover the task, I thought it would be great if they could go into their task events on the SharePoint calendar for that day, doubleclick into the event and have some kind of option to send it to someone's Outlook as a meeting as a sort of reminder for the covering person to handle the task.